# How to output value on all td's with same id?

Tags: javascript, html-table

How can I output values in all `td`'s with the same id?
I want to sum the value of dropdown 1 and dropdown 2 and output it in the cells with the same id. So far I've made it to output only in the first cell.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sum = document.getElementById("month").value;
  var sumo = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var p = Math.floor(Number(sum) + Number(sumo));
  console.log(p);
  $("#sum").html(p);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="Jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div id="output">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <select name="date" id="month" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <select name="year" id="year" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr id="num">
      <td id="sum">1</th>
        <td id="sum">1</th>
          <td id="sum">1</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `all td's with same id?` That is invalid HTML.

Comment: `$("td[id^='sum']").html(p);` will help you.

Comment: Why dont you use **class** instead you same **id**

Comment: yeah, i forgot about classes. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @BobyMarley, Please don't forget to read, vote and/or accept answer(s) as it will help future users and encourage other users to respond. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ids need to be **unique**.

> The [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) global attribute defines a unique identifier which must be **unique in the whole document**.

You can do this using **[class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)** names instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sum = document.getElementById("month").value;
  var sumo = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var p = Math.floor(Number(sum) + Number(sumo));
  console.log(p);
  $.each($('.myClassName'), function() {
    this.innerHTML = p;

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="Jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div id="output">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <select name="date" id="month" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <select name="year" id="year" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr id="num">
      <td class="myClassName" id="sum1">1</th>
        <td class="myClassName" id="sum2">1</th>
          <td class="myClassName" id="sum3">1</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```